# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: _Xmx2048M Unrecognized option: _Xmx2048M Minecraft server

Tags: java, server, minecraft

When trying to set up my minecraft server I get the following error and I am unclear of how to fix the problem.

I have tried changing environment settings and can get a 1GB server to run but It cant handle 2GB
Any help would be appreciated

command prompt error message-

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\server>java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar 

minecraft_server.1.14.4.jar nogui

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: _Xmx2G

Unrecognized option: _Xmx2G

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `_JAVA_OPTIONS` defined in your environment. Make sure to unset it. You can do it inside environment settings.

You can find sample here: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

try this  set _JAVA_OPTIONS=Xmx1024M

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).